# javascript ok cancel pop-up button

Tags: javascript

I've tried a lot of things, but still can access a .js file from inside a form: please, can anyone tell me how it can be done?

this is what I am trying to call:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (confirm("Press 'OK' to leave, or 'Cancel' if you want to stay: "))
    {         
       window.location="http://google.com";
    }
    else
    {         
      <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a> 
    }
  </script>
```

this is how I've been trying to call:

```
<input type="BUTTON" value="Back to Main Page" onclick= ??? >
```

Thank you.

Comment: I advice you to first read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide. While we have been all beginners once and of course also answer basic questions, you need to learn *some* basics first. If you cannot get something to work, look again at the tutorial. Asking for every single problem you have here doesn't help you much. You have to learn how to help yourself too.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend starting [here](http://www.pagetutor.com/javascript/lesson01.html). MDC's Javascript Guide is not exactly for beginners.

Comment: You clearly do not understand the very basics of Javascript.  Don't just dive in and try to use a programming language you don't understand.  Learn to do it the right way.  There are any number of tutorials online to help you!

Answer (score 3):

```
var answer = confirm ("Press Ok to leave. Cancel to stay.")
   if (answer)
window.location="http://google.com"
   else
window.location="http://www.mysite.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding HTML code inside of your JavaScript code. You need to separate them. Something like:

`document.write('<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>');`

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your code into a [javascript function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), like this

```
function sayHello()
{
  alert('hello');
}
```

And in the button html:

```
<input type="BUTTON" value="Back to Main Page" onclick="javascript: sayHello();" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am pretty new to programming, but still trying to built a website. I am trying to create a .js file containing the function, so then I will be able to call it from all pages. Could you please give a hint about how it can be done?

Comment: Basically you add something like <script type="text/javascript" src="your-script-file.js"></script> to all the .html pages, but it sounds like you should really find a good book on Javascript.

Answer (score -2):

```
//  start active and inactive confirm message box
    var Regionid = '@Model.RegionID';
    if (Regionid != 0) {
        $(function () {
            $('#inactive').change(function () {
                $("#ConformationDlg").html('@Constants.ChangeStatus');
                $("#ConformationDlg").dialog({
                    title: "",
                    buttons: [
                       {
                           text: "Yes",
                           click: function () {
                               $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                           }
                       },
                    {
                        text: "No",
                        click: function () {
                            $('#active').prop("checked", true);
                            $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
            });
        })
    }
    //  End active and inactive confirm message box
$(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        var form = $("#frm");
        var Regionid = $("#hdnRegionID").val();
        if (form.valid()) {
            if (Regionid == 0) {

                $("#ConformationDlg").html('@Constants.AddFormSubmit');
                $("#ConformationDlg").dialog({
                    title: "",
                    buttons: [
                       {
                           text: "Yes",
                           click: function () {
                               window.location.href = "../RegionFoodTypes/RegionFoodTypes";
                               $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                           }
                       },
                    {
                        text: "No",
                        click: function () {
                            $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
            }
            else {

                $("#ConformationDlg").html('@Constants.EditFormSubmit');
                $("#ConformationDlg").dialog({
                    title: "",
                    buttons: [
                       {
                           text: "Yes",
                           click: function () {
                               window.location.href = "../RegionFoodTypes/RegionFoodTypes";
                               $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                           }
                       },
                    {
                        text: "No",
                        click: function () {
                            $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });

            }
        }
    })

})
function resetFields(form) {
    $("#ConformationDlg").html('@Constants.CancelForm');
    $("#ConformationDlg").dialog({
        title: "",
        buttons: [
           {
               text: "Yes",
               click: function () {
                   window.location.href = "../RegionFoodTypes/RegionFoodTypes";
                   $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
               }
           },
        {
            text: "No",
            click: function () {
                $("#ConformationDlg").dialog("close");
            }
        }
        ]
    });
}
```