# How to pass the dropdown and text value to my email?

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have one HTML page with 4 text box, 1 dropdown and 1 button, doe anybody know how I could send these values to my email through javascript so that when you click on verstuur (send) you will get a javascript notification message with (message send or Please check all fields and try again.)

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <div class="row">
        <p>
            <label>Volledige Naam</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="text_field" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>E-mailadres</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="text_field" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>
            <label>Telefoonnummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="text_field" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Onderwerp</label>
                <select class="text_field" name="subject">
                <option>Selecteer een onderwerp</option>
                 <option value="afspraak">Afspraak Maken</option>
                 <option value="informatie">Informatie Opvragen</option>
                 <option value="klacht">Klacht</option>
                 <option value="overig">Overig</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label>Bericht</label>
        <textarea class="text_field" rows="10" cols="10" name="message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Verstuur" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think you want a Javascript confirmation dialogue, here's a simple example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5099696/1781026

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an email directly from JavaScript. You'll need to use some kind of server side technology (like for ex: PHP) to do this. You can issue an AJAX request to that script via JS and get your mail sent.

You can however, dynamically create a `mailto:` link so that the browser can open up the user's default mail application form where he can send it.

Comment: And could somebody make a example please because i can't script php of ajax thanks in advance